# How can I add an MSBuild Import with IVsBuildPropertyStorage?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to add an Import task to a .csproj file programmatically, but I don't want to use the Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine objects to do this because VS will then pop up warnings about the project file being modified from outside of Visual Studio.

I've seen a few pages [1] [2] suggesting that the IVsBuildPropertyStorage interface will let me access the MSBuild parts of the .csproj file, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this, or if it's even possible really.  It looks like I need to specify the name of the property I want to access, but I'm not sure how to figure that out.  Calling GetPropertyValue() for an "Import" property doesn't return anything for project files that are already set up how I want my final results to look:

```
EnvDTE.Project proj = ...;
var sol = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(VsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
IVsHierarchy hier;
sol.GetProjectOfUniqueName(p.UniqueName, out hier);
var storage = hier as IVsBuildPropertyStorage;
string val;
storage.GetPropertyValue("Import", String.Empty,
                         (uint)_PersistStorageType.PST_PROJECT_FILE, out val);
// val is null
```

[1] https://mpfproj.svn.codeplex.com/svn/9.0/Tests/UnitTests/ProjectTest.cs

[2] http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/e1983591-120a-4a2f-a910-e596dd625e68

Thanks.  I'd appreciate any suggestions I can get with this.

Comment: Maybe there's any easier way. Why do you want to modify your .csproj? Could a hardcoded `<Import />` with a condition provide what you need?

Comment: I just saw your previous post explaining what you're after.

Comment: any solution with full source code?

Answer (score 6):

I asked a similar question see here [Programmatically adding and editing the Targets in a Visual Studio Project File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4511344/17822)  What you can do to add an import to the project file programmatically is to use this namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction.aspx which is from the assembly (in the GAC) Microsoft.Build.dll.  You can accomplish this in about 3-4 steps:

the following is pseudo code:

1. Get the Project File location using the DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects and getting the Properties of each Project.  Get the FullPath and the FileName to get the full path of the project file.
2. Once you have the full path of the project file, call the [ProjectRootElement.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd234277.aspx) static method:

   ProjectRootElement project = ProjectRootElement.Open(projectPath);
3. Once you have the ProjectRootElement reference, you can call the [AddImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction.projectrootelement.addimport.aspx) method (where name is the Project Identifier Attribute):

   project.AddImport(name)

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore that option when I get back to this issue.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the file is modified out-of-process, so Visual Studio will ask to reload the file.

Answer (score 2):

`Import` element is not a `Property` element in MSBuild nor and `Item` one.

I think you can't add an `Import` using `IVsBuildPropertyStorage`.