# Programmatically adding and editing the Targets in a Visual Studio Project File

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to programmatically add the following Target to my Visual Studio Project File.

```
<Target Name="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(PostBuildEvent)'!=''" DependsOnTargets="$(PostBuildEventDependsOn)">
      <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
</Target>
```

I am pretty sure that `IVsBuildPropertyStorage` or `IVsBuildPropertyStorage2` will not work because the require a ProjectItem aka a node from the `<ItemGroup>` element in the project file.  What I would like to do is add the above xml outside the `<ItemGroup>` element.

I am trying to use the Visual Studio SDK to do this and the documentation & examples on doing this exact thing seems to be lacking.  As of the time of this post I am unable to find a way of doing this.  I would **really like to avoid** loading up the project file (in this case Test.csproj) as an `XDocument` or an `XmlDocument` and adding the Target element node that way.  It seems messy and could cause more problems.

As an added bonus I would also like to IgnoreOnExit a single `PostBuildEvent` element, but I am pretty sure that this is not possible with the `PostBuildEvent` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [AddTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction.projectrootelement.addtarget.aspx) method on the [ProjectRootElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction.projectrootelement.aspx) class in the `Microsoft.Build.Construction` namespace.  That namespace is used to read and write MSBuild files.